# Using generating functions, find the number of solutions of the equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

so I've searched a lot about this and I've seen a few solutions but I didn't understand any of them.

I have this equation which I'm meant to use generating functions to find the number of solutions of this equations:

u1 + u2 + ... + u7 = 16, where   1<= ui <= 5 and  i= 1, ..., 7. 
(I've also included a screenshot of the question for more clarity.

https://gyazo.com/0b1922b9c01d99487e095353aca5a079

So I know I have sample solutions for similar questions but I can't follow their working. Here is a sample solution: 
https://gyazo.com/babd84f939d4a8df3c83730c5ef4e802

I can do all the way up line 5 of the solution section but I don't understand how g(X) returns that function and then also how do they get the solution from g(X) ???

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please [do not use image for the critical part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: you should watch this video about generating functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-drdeNMoe8w

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider $(u+u^2+...+u^5)^7$, specifically the coefficient in front of $u^{16}$.

Comment: So I got up to:
X^7(1+X+...+X^4)^7 
but then what comes next?

Comment: That’s a nice reduction as you now need to find the $u^9$ coefficient of the second piece. To do so you could either brute force the expansion (discarding anything bigger than $u^9$ along the way) or you could take 9 derivatives and evaluate at 0.

Comment: Why do I need to find u^9 ?

Comment: I’m dividing both sides by $u^7$ (or $X^7$) in your notation.

Comment: so the co efficient of u^9 would be 7*6*5, or am i wrong here?